# php code to shortcode

Tags: shortcode

So, this is the php code that I have:

```
<?php global $royal_profile;?>
    <div class="profile-img" data-key="profilepicture">
        <?php echo get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 64 ); ?>
    </div>
```

Then here is my attempt to turn it into a shortcode (so that I can use in a menu as I realized that I can't simply put php into the menu.

```
function wpse_143641_profile_shortcode( $atts ) {
  return <<<royal_profile

       <?php global $royal_profile;?>
    <div class="profile-img" data-key="profilepicture">
        <?php echo get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 64 ); ?>
    </div>

royal_profile;
 }
add_shortcode( 'royal_profile', 'wpse_143641_profile_shortcode' );
```

When I inspect the element on the frontend, following is the result I got.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to put a shortcode in a **menu**?

Comment: mhmm, I am trying replace the menu item title with the avatar.

Comment: Please do not duplicate questions.

Comment: hmm didn't realized it was asked before. Thanks for the notice

Comment: It was asked before ***by you***. You didn't need a "notice" to know that.

Comment: Excuse me, if I didn't remember it or notice it, that is the end of the story. Whether it was the case or not is none of your business. Don't tell me what I need or don't. Thank you.

Comment: [Be nice.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Please mind your manners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You can use this code.

```
function wpse_143641_profile_shortcode( $atts ) 
  {
   echo get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), 64 );
  }
add_shortcode( 'royal_profile', 'wpse_143641_profile_shortcode' );
```

And you should add the short code in your editor

```
[royal_profile]
```

or template

```
do_shortcode('[royal_profile]')
```

Comment: Never echo anything from a shortcode, all output should be **returned**. Echoing output will result in unexpected behavior

Comment: Though this answer was accepted I don't see how it could answer the question-- "...into a shortcode (***so that I can use in a menu*** as I realized that I can't simply put php into the menu." Menus don't, to my knowledge, process shortcodes. There would be additional work to be done.